# React Native: How to detect phone with dynamic island?

Tags: react-native, dynamic-island

Is it possible to target phones (iPhone 14 Pro and iPhone 14 Pro Max) with dynamic islands with React Native?

Answer (score 7):

Just to complement the other answer it is also possible to use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)

```
  const iPhonesWithDynamicIsland = ['iPhone15,2', 'iPhone15,3']; // iPhone 14 Pro, iPhone 14 Pro Max
  const isIphoneWithDynamicIsland = iPhonesWithDynamicIsland.includes(DeviceInfo.getDeviceId());
  console.log(isIphoneWithDynamicIsland);
```

or even simpler:

```
DeviceInfo.hasDynamicIsland()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply detect an iPhone with a dynamic island by using `react-native-safe-area-context` by getting the height/top of it, if it was `59` then this iPhone has a dynamic island

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
console.log(insets.top == 59 ? true : false ) // has dynamic 


// this is some of the other heights of other iPhones
59 - iPhone 14 Pro / 14Pro Max
50 - iPhone 13 mini
47 - iPhone 12 / 12Pro / 13 / 13Pro / 13Pro Max / 14 / 14 Plus
44 - on iPhoneX
20 - on iOS device
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-device-info`'s `hasDynamicIsland()` method.

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

let hasDynamicIsland = DeviceInfo.hasDynamicIsland();
// true
```

here is the link for more info [react-native-device-info - hasDynamicIsland()](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#hasDynamicIsland)